# ANGULAR error : 'app-header' is not a known element: Angular 9

Tags: angular, typescript, angular9

I have migrated my angular application from version 5 to version 9. When I try to run my application it is throwing below error

[image]

Please find my code details below.

**app.module.ts**

```
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './header/header.component';
    
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
  ],

  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
   ],
  schemas: [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {

}
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor( 

  ngOnInit(): void {
   
  }

}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<app-header>

</app-header>
<script src="../../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../node_modules/jqueryui/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="circle">
  <div class="loader">
    <div class="loader">
        <div class="loader">
           
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div> 

<div id="container"> 
  <div id="test1" class="test1"></div>
</div>
```

**app.header.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html'
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  
  }    
}
```

Note :

1. I have not define any extra module for headers
2. I have defined the header component in '**declaration**' of app.module.ts file.
3. The application was working fine until I migrated to version 8. After upgrading to version 9 it is throwing and error.

Answer (score -1):

After updated angular version

if you want to declare `components` in one module and use them in another module you need to export them so that when you will import the module in another module, it will understand that these will be used from another module

so in your `app.module.ts` declare and also export them so that the index module should understand that these are from other modules.

**app.module.ts**

```
exports: [
  HeaderComponent,
],
```

Comment: The OP declared the `HeaderComponent` in `AppModule` already.